# Regex get text after square bracket

Tags: regex

I have a string which I want to match with regex. I want to get to get the text after the `[*]`
So for the following string... I should have 5 matches... since there are 5 lines after `[*]`.

```
[a]
Text

[b]
Text

[c]
Text

[d]
Text

[e]
Text
```

I tried using:

```
[^\]]*$
```

But it only gets the last match

Comment: Try `(?m)^\[[^\]\[]*\]\R\K.+`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/SohdOL/3).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```php
(?m)^\[[^][]*]\R\K.+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SohdOL/3).

*Details*:

- `(?m)` - multiline mode on
- `^` - start of a line
- `\[[^][]*]` - a `[`, zero or more chars other than `[` and `]` and then a `]`
- `\R` - a line break sequence
- `\K` - an operator that discards all text matched so far
- `.+` - a non-empty line

Comment: This doesn't work for multi lines. I used ```(?m)(^\w+)+``` instead but then it only does 1 word

Comment: @HeelMega Then try using `(?m)^\[[^][]*]\R\K.+(?:\R.+)*(?=\R{2}|\z)`, see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SohdOL/6).

Comment: that works! thank you. Quick question... is there an alternative to ```\K```? It doesn't work in .net regex https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference

Comment: @HeelMega In .NET, you would rather use `(?m)(?<=^\[[^][]*]\r?\n).+(?:\n.+)*?(?=(?:\r?\n){2}|\z)`.

Comment: I have been stuck on this for hours... you are a genius! thank you

Comment: @HeelMega Just note that in .NET regex, `.` matches CR chars. In order to trim off `\r`, you can use `(?m)(?<=^\[[^][]*]\r?\n)[^\r\n]+(?:\r?\n[^\r\n]+)*?(?=(?:\r?\n){2}|\z)`. See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fm%29%28%3f%3c%3d%5e%5c%5b%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d*%5d%5cr%3f%5cn%29%5b%5e%5cr%5cn%5d%2b%28%3f%3a%5cr%3f%5cn%5b%5e%5cr%5cn%5d%2b%29*%3f%28%3f%3d%28%3f%3a%5cr%3f%5cn%29%7b2%7d%7c%5cz%29&i=%5ba%5d%0d%0aText%0d%0aMore+here%0d%0a%0d%0a%5bb%5d%0d%0aText%0d%0a%0d%0a%5bc%5d%0d%0aText).